# adding a payment gateway to the WSO2 api gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I would like to do a small proof of concept and integrate a Paypal payment page while a developer signs up for an API. Do we have any ready reckoner or sample code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in latest API Manager 1.10.0 version. There was a feature in 1.10.0 version in which we can do a HTTP redirection from subscription workflow. You can redirect to your billing page to do the payment stuffs. For more details refer the [wso2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+HTTP+Redirection+for+Workflows).

quoted from documentation

> consider an API Manager user publishes an API and wants to make that
>   API a chargeable API. If there are no payment details of the
>   subscriber, that subscriber is forwarded to a third party entity that
>   handles the payment detail collection